# Geometry Inequality Proof: show one side greater than another

Tags: geometry

[image: Geometry Inequality proof]

Can someone refresh my memory how to prove this. I am going to be tutoring a high school student. I know $\angle 1 = \angle 2$ and $EG$ is congruent to itself but where do I go from there?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Angle $3$ is an exterior angle of triangle EFG, hence angle $3$ > angle $2=$ angle $1$. Then apply the law of sines.

This works directly if angle $3$ is acute. If it is obtuse, angle $FEG$ is acute, and $>$ angle $1=$ angle $2$…

Comment: Yeah, clearer than the way I put it.  There is a caveat that an angle could be larger and yet have a smaller sine (but of course that is easily taken care of, since those two angles could not be part of the same triangle).

Comment: I've just addressed the case $3$ is obtuse.

Comment: Oh, I think it was fine.  Surely the OP can take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

**Basic approach.** The parallel postulate tells you that $m\angle DEG > m\angle EGF = m\angle EGD$, and therefore $DG > DE$ (larger sides are opposite larger angles, given that $\angle EGD$ is acute—it is half of an angle within a triangle—and $\angle EGD$ and $\angle DEG$ add up to less than $180$ degrees).